# Unknown Scheme interpreter inqueries

Tags: scheme, ansys

I am working with ANSYS Fluent solver which has a built-in Scheme interpreter in the Text User Interface that allows scheme journals to be sourced for batch runs. Unfortunately the interpreter is not documented by the vendor being assumed to be internal part;
though users worldwide use the built-in interpreter to automate some tasks, like reporting of results for example.

Is there a way how to get more knowledge about the interpreter by using some standard scheme queries? To acquire the scheme version or standard it is using or list of functions available for using?

Generally, what could a user do who knows nothing about the interpreter, to get information to start with?

Comment: You can use one of the Scheme conformance test floating around in the net: [R4RS](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/*checkout*/scm/scm/r4rstest.scm?revision=HEAD)

Comment: @ceving useful. Unfortunately the script fails soon, the interpreter is not using "list?". Is there a way how to print out all the functions known to the environment? I am not schemer. Any hint is welcomed.